# Can I create models.py Models that load data from the file system (NOT from a database)?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

We have a test tool that produces test results following a directory structure like follows:

```
test-results/${TEST-ID}/exec_${YYYYMMDD}_${HHMMSS}/
```

Inside each ***exec*** folder, there are several files like CSVs, HTML reports, charts, etc. The structure is always the same, and for simplicity's sake we don't use a database.

Now I would like to use Django to build a simple website for displaying these test results. Think of a reporting website, with some basic functionality like comparing test executions against each other.

From reading [The Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/), I understand that in a Django app I should define my data in `models.py` using classes that extend `django.db.models.Model`, and later work with the API (e.g.  `object.save()`, `object.delete()`, etc.) while the framework takes care of the database operations.

My data is a set of test results, which lives on a file system, not in a database.

That said, I would like to keep the data abstraction in `models.py` (i.e. to keep the MVC abstraction). The Django app only needs to read data, e.g.:

- `TestResult.objects.all()` would load all TestResults from the `test-results` directory
- `TestResult.objects.filter(test_id=1)` would return all TestResults for TEST-ID 1
- and so on.

Updating data is not necessary; the app only reads data from the file system and displays it.

Can I achieve this behaviour using Django?

My current assumption is that I have to write the abstraction layer somewhere (extend the `Model` class and overwrite certain methods?), but I'm not sure this is the best/correct approach.

Comment: django comes with support for multiple database backends, perhaps you could look at how they are implemented and extend what they are doing to your own filesystem backend https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/db/backends

Comment: I believe it would be simpler, faster and better to just import you CSVs into a simple database, like SQLite. This way you won't have to spend time reinventing Django's ORM and the only drawback that comes to mind is the duplication of the data.